# Display data from POST request Swift

Tags: ios, swift

New to swift and wanted to display some data from a post request each time a user presses a button.

Class and struct for Post request:

```
    import Foundation
    
struct Response: Codable, Identifiable{
    
    var id = UUID()
    var model = String()
    var choices = String()
    var generatedtext: [GeneratedText]

    
}
    
    struct GeneratedText: Codable{
        
        var finish_reason = String()
        var index = Int()
        var logprobs = String()
        var text = String()
    }
    
    
    
    class GPT3TextComepletion: ObservableObject{
        
        @Published var response = [Response]()
        
        
        func textCompletion(promptText:String, completion:@escaping  ([Response]) -> () ){
            
            let token = "redacted"
            let url = URL(string: "redacted URL")!
    
            // prepare json data
            var json: [String: Any] = [
                                         "temperature": 0.8,
                                         "max_tokens": 64,
                                         "top_p": 1,
                                         "frequency_penalty": 0,
                                         "presence_penalty": 0,
                                         "stop": ["\n\n"]]
            json["prompt"] = promptText
    
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    
            // create post request
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
            // insert json data to the request
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                    return
                }
                //TODO: Remove this once i get the response to display
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                    print(responseJSON)
                }
                
                let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Response].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(response)
                }
            }
            
    
            task.resume()
        }
    
    
    }
```

View:

Removed the unnecessary styling and other code from the below view:

```
 @State var prompt: String = "This is some editable text..."
 @State var response = [Response]()

    utton(action: {GPT3TextComepletion().textCompletion(promptText: prompt, completion: {(response) in self.response = response })}) 
              List (response){ response in
                  VStack{
                      Text(response.model)}}
```

However upon running the emulator and attempting the post call there seems to be an issue with how i am decoding the data and most likely how i have organized my structs, error message:

*"Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."*

JSON:

```
["id": cmpl-4PCJZrxEm8YlCwFSTZlfLpnAUcMPl, "created": 1641910885, "object": text_completion, "model": davinci:2020-05-03, "choices": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6000012f1dc0>(
{
    "finish_reason" = stop;
    index = 0;
    logprobs = "<null>";
    text = "";
}
)
]
```

Obviously i am doing something wrong with how i am defining my struct however I have tried a number of different things with no success over the last few days.

Two main questions:

1. Is there an alternate way to display response of the post request without using List and making the struct identifiable?
2. What I am doing wrong with my structs here?

Thanks!

Comment: `decode([Response].self` => `decode(Response.self`, and then `completion(response)` => `completion([response])`

Comment: `id` is not a valid `UUID` as said by the error. Just make is a `String`.

Comment: Yes sorry deleted my comment earlier as i realized. Thank you very much for your help!! If you post as a answer i can mark as accepted